# OpenCart Change Pagination Links to SEO links

Tags: php, nginx, preg-replace, str-replace, opencart

I am trying to replace my Pagination within OpenCart.

From this:

```
$pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&page={page}');
// Spits out 
www.site.com/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=QUERY&page=2
```

to this:

```
$pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&page={page}');
// Spits out 
www.site.com/search?q=QUERY&page=2
```

The file is in ***/catalog/controller/product/search.php*** (OC 1.5 near line 438-444). The full block of code:

```
$pagination = new Pagination();
$pagination->total = $product_total;
$pagination->page = $page;
$pagination->limit = $limit;
$pagination->text = $this->language->get('text_pagination');

$pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&page={page}');
$this->data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();
```

Comment: This is a good question, I look forward to seeing the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want see in answer. nginx config?

Comment: I want to see the OpenCart SEO format - I basically don't want the `index.php?route=` part - nothing to do with Nginx really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have a .htaccess file setup and you are already using the SEO built into OpenCart 1.5.  If not, here are some pretty good instructions: [Adding SEO Friendly URL’S to OpenCart](http://kevindees.cc/2011/11/adding-seo-friendly-urls-to-opencart/) by Kevin Dees

This is a partial hack, but if all you want to fix is the pagination, it should work.

First you need to add 3 lines to the .htaccess file I referenced earlier.  After this line:

```
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
```

Add:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=([^&]*) [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} .*search$
RewriteRule search$ /index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=%1 [L,QSA]
```

So in all that section of the .htaccess file should look like:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule sitemap.xml /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=([^&]*) [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} .*search$
RewriteRule search$ /index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=%1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Next you need to modify the **/catalog/controller/product/search.php** to generate the correct url.  I commented out the line that generates the link and added my own 2 lines above it(you'll need replace *http://www.example.com* with your own info):

```
$pagination = new Pagination();
$pagination->total = $product_total;
$pagination->page = $page;
$pagination->limit = $limit;
$pagination->text = $this->language->get('text_pagination');

$url = preg_replace("/filter_name/","q",$url);
$pagination->url = "http://www.example.com/search?".$url."&page={page}";
//$pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&page={page}');

$this->data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();
```

**Resources:**

- I found some of the basics of RewriteRules from: [RoScripts.com Pretty URLs - a guide to URL rewriting](http://www.roscripts.com/Pretty_URLs_-_a_guide_to_URL_rewriting-168.html).
- Here's an example of how to pull from the query string from a blog comment by Nidaan [here](http://vikrant_labde.blogspot.com/2008/07/querystring-in-htaccess-match-question.html?showComment=1302329313209#c3513759857163698994).
- And finally for everything else regarding Apache's mod_rewrite visit: [Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)